# Pre-built Ubuntu setup for deep learning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, computer-vision, deep-learning

I want to work on deep learning and computer vision in Linux, say Ubuntu.

I know there are pre-built images in AWS, Azure for this purpose.

But I want to install it on my PC to VirtualBox or to hard drive.

Are there any available images/setups for Ubuntu or other Linux with preinstalled popular deep learning/computer vision frameworks?

Comment: If you are using Virtualbox, remember that Tensorflow uses the GPU heavily. So you must make sure that the 3D support of the Hypervisor is enabled properly, that the correct 3rd party drivers are installed and that your GPU is supported at all. (I'm not sure if this setup works *at all*)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

[Link for the Image(VMware)](https://archive.org/details/DeepLearningVM_Ubuntu_16.04_64Bit_vmware)

[Link for VitualBox](https://archive.org/details/DeepLearningVMForVirtualBox.tar)

**VMware  shared by Adam G**

The virtual machine image has Ubuntu Linux Desktop 16.04 LTS 64-bit pre-installed with the following machine learning tools:

```
Python 3.5
OpenCV 3.2 with Python 3 bindings
dlib 19.4 with Python 3 bindings
TensorFlow 1.0 for Python 3
Keras 2.0 for Python 3
Theano
face_recognition for Python 3 (for playing around with face recognition)
PyCharm Community Edition already set up and ready to go for all these libraries Convenient code examples ready to run, right on the desktop!
Even the webcam is preconfigured to work inside the Linux VM for OpenCV / face_recognition examples (as long as you set up your webcam to be accessible in the VMware settings).
```